# Unable to assign Mat Table dataSource to test data while testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material, angular-test

I am trying to assign test data to my angular material table during testing but cannot get it to work.

.spec.ts

```
  let testCustomers: Customer[] = [ ... my Data...]
  ....
  it("should test the table", (done) => {
    component.defaultData = testCustomers;
    //Filter table does some work to the data and then assigns it to sortedData
    component.filterTable();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      let rows = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("mat-row");
      expect(rows.length).toEqual(3);
      done();
    });
  });
```

.ts file: My ngOnInit calls a function that makes a http request and gets my data and assigns the data to a variable called 'sortedData'

.html  `...    <mat-table id="table" [dataSource]="sortedData" matSort...`

The table itself works perfectly. But I do not know how to assign dummy data during ng test

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Expected 0 to equal 3? Make sure you have `MatTableModule` in the `imports` array so the TestBed knows how to paint the MatTable.

Comment: The import is there. I have other tests reading the column header too

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure then.